# How to avoid including an unwanted `+` separator in a label for my dice game?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, for-loop, random

I have a problem with a simple Windows Forms program. The program is a dice game:

- The user writes into a textbox how many dice they want to roll.
- The application rolls the number of dice entered.
- The application shows the value of each die as well as the total across all rolled dice in a label.

Example: If I roll 4 dice, the application should show their values together with the sum of their values, such as: 4 + 3 + 6 + 1 = 14.

I don't know how to make my application decide if it rolled the dice enough times before writing an extra `+` sign out.

Right now, the application shows the result of rolling 3 dice like:

> 3 + 3 + 3 += 9

But I don't want that last `+` in the label – I want it to only write `= 9`, not `+= 9`.

This is how my code looks now:

```
private void throwDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfDices = int.Parse(dicesTextBox.Text);
    int sum = 0;
    showLabel.Text = "";

    if (numberOfDices == 1)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dice1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
        sum = dice1;
        showLabel.Text = dice1 + " = " + sum;
    }
    else if (numberOfDices > 1)
    {
        Random rand1 = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfDices; i++)
        {
            int dice = rand1.Next(1, 7);
            sum += dice;

            if (i != numberOfDices)
            {
                showLabel.Text += dice.ToString() + " + ";
            }
            else
            {
                showLabel.Text += "=" + sum.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `if (i != antal)` to `if (i < numberOfDices)` and `visaLabel.Text += "=" + summa.ToString();` to `visaLabel.Text += dice.ToString() + " = " + sum.ToString();`.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant approach could be:

```
private void throwDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfDices = int.Parse(dicesTextBox.Text);
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 1;
    showLabel.Text = "";

    do
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dice1 = rand.Next(1, 7);
        sum += dice1;
        showLabel.Text += string.Format("{0} {1}", dice1.ToString(), i ==  numberOfDices ? " = " + sum.ToString() : " + ");
        i++;
    } while (i <= numberOfDices);       
}
```

Comment: To add a bit more randomness to the dice roll, you could put a call to: Thread.Sleep(100); right after the i++; within the while loop.

Comment: I posted an edit to my original answer. Please make sure the i++ statement is at the end of the do while loop.